# Ruby subprocess with node.js

Tags: javascript, ruby, node.js, subprocess

I'm trying to launch a ruby instance as subprocess of my node program. In fact, everything is OK but I just can't interact with the ruby's STDIN and STDOUT. (of course the ruby program works in my terminal with my keyboard input)

So this is a simplified code that I want to get working ...

simpleproc.js

```
var util   = require('util'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
    ruby  = spawn('ruby', [__dirname + '/process.rb']);

ruby.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

ruby.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

ruby.on('exit', function (code) {
  console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});

ruby.stdin.write("ping\n");
```

process.rb

```
f = File.new("process.log", "w")
f.write "=== Hello! ===\n"
STDIN.each_line do |line|
   STDOUT.write line
   f.write line
end
```

What's wrong with it ? I've already managed to get an another process working... but here, there is no IO ! Nothing happens !

EDIT: I modified the ruby file to show that, with node, the file is only written with `=== Hello! ===\n` inside. So we can say that, the ruby file is correctly launched but doesn't receive anything from node (I've tried to flush after the `STDOUT.write` but the do statement is never executed.

Comment: I tried using your example, but ruby seems to hang before it even creates that log file. Any ideas? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902641/node-js-ruby-subprocess-hangs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `STDOUT.flush` on the ruby side after `STDOUT.write`,
as the output is being buffered.

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work because the ruby STDIN, doesn't receive anything. If I try to write in a file in the do statement, nothing happens anyway. So, I can't see where the problem is. But that's maybe due to my node's version (master branch in the github repo).

Comment: Maybe it's the version. Using node 0.4.2 and ruby 1.8.7 (Mac) your code works for me after I add a flush (silence without it). Writing to a file or to node from ruby should not make a difference.

Comment: Oh boy ! In fact I wrote this `ruby.stdin.write("ping");` in my own JS file. But thank you anyway, your answer was good because without the flush instruction, there was no way to get it working ! Thanks !